# What is the accusative case for adjectives?

Tags: прилагательные

When would I use the accusative case for adjectives? I get that there are different endings for different cases but I don't understand how to use the accusative case. 
If you could use examples, that would be great! Thanks!

Btw, isn't the accusative case like: me, him, her, you, it, us, them ? Or am I completely wrong?

Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case

Comment: Do you understand when you might use the accusative case for *nouns*?

Comment: Cases do not directly translate between languages, even the most closely related, like Russian and Ukrainian. In some cases English "me" would translate as Russian *меня*, in other cases it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russian adjectives always agree with the nouns, so whenever an adjective belongs to an object, you would likely put in the accusative:

- **синяя** краска  (nominative)
- Я взял **синюю** краску (accusative)

In English, the object form (me, you, him, her) often corresponds to Accusative in Russian, but it may also correspond to Nominative ("you and me"), Genitive ("without me"), Dative ("tell me please") and other cases

Comment: It is considered a mistake in English to use "you and me" as nominative: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me

Comment: @AndreyRybak: I agree, that usage is not quite correct, but this exchange is not about English :)
A better example of the object case corresponding to the Russian Nominative would be "He is just like me" (он совсем как я)